# Determine whether there is a path from vertex u to w passing through v

Tags: algorithm, graph, path, ford-fulkerson

Given an undirected graph `G = (V, E)`, such that `u`, `v`, `w` are some edges in G.

Describe an algorithm to determine whether

*"if there is a path from u to w that passes through v"*

A simple algorithm for that using DFS is given below:

```
bool checkFunction(){

  graph g; // containing u, w, v
  dfs(v);

  if(isVisited(u) && isVisited(w))
    return true;
  else
    return false;
   
}
```

For the above algorithm,

- time complexity    :    O(V+E)
- space complexity   :    O(V)

But can we reduce the time complexity?

Comment: There are abundant tutorials on the internet about this. You also didn't show any effort to at least initiate the solution (i.e. by showing what you have done so far).

Comment: First of all, welcome to SO @AnupamKumar. Please edit to add useful information like links about the techniques you already know and you mentioned; research that you did; and why not a minimal reproducible code in your language, so that we can experiment too, based on your initial approach. This will encourage more people to try to solve your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any more constraints, there aren't any available optimizations that aren't kind of obvious.

A path exists iff *u*, *v*, and *w* are in the same connected component.   That can be easily determined by running a BFS or DFS from any one to see if it finds the other two.

For some graphs there is an opportunity to do better when a path does *not* exist and one of the vertices is in a small connected component.  You can do a single BFS from your initial 3 vertices, and when you discover a new vertex, remember which source it came from.   You will also find connections when you discover a redundant edge from, for example, a *u* vertex to a *v* vertex.  If you run out of edges from any one source before all 3 are connected, then you can stop, because you know that that vertex is isolated.

Answer (score 14):

**Note:** This post doesn't provide a solution to the question posted, but it does provide some information regarding common mistakes one can make while solving such problems.

(This post also assumes paths to not allow duplicate vertices. If you remove this constraint, the problem can be solved easily by finding a path from u to v, and a path from v to w and just concatenating these 2 paths to get a [walk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)#Walk,_trail,_path) from u to w passing through v. This can be achieved by running BFS once from u and once from v)

The [answer given by amit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62744121/102937) isn't correct.

---

**Edit:**
The below counter example is incorrect, see the comment by Steve. I have provided another counter example after this one.
Consider a counter example.
V = {u, v, w, x}
E = {{u,v}, {u,w}, {u,x}, {v,x}, {w,x}}
Then, the path (u,v,x,w) is a valid path.
Now lets say we apply BFS on w, the corresponding paths (not unique) we get from w to u and w to v will be (w,u) and (w, u, v)
Now, the "path" (v,u,w,u) has a repeated node u, so it's not a path.

---

Another counter example:
Consider V = {u,v,w,x,y,z} E = {{u,x}, {v,x}, {x,w}, {v,y}, {y,z}, {z,w}}
A BFS Tree from w will have the edges {{w,x}, {w,z}, {x,u}, {x,v}} (we treat u,v as sinks)
This gives the "path" {u,x,w,x,v} which is invalid

The [answer by Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62744090/102937) is also incorrect.

> A path exists iff u, v, and w are in the same connected component.

Consider a line graph {w, u, v}, then all these 3 lie in the same connected component, but there is no path from u to w that passes through v

---

This problem (for undirected graphs) is also stated [here](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/64maxflow/) (See problem 7), which I think is a reputable source, so we can safely assume that there does exist an efficient algorithm for this.
[This](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20185/subgraph-containing-all-nodes-and-edges-that-are-part-of-length-limited-simple-s/21809) also argues for the existence of a solution, as well as provides an algorithm.
For directed graphs, this is a ["hard" problem](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20137/subgraph-containing-all-nodes-and-edges-that-are-part-of-length-limited-simple-s).

Comment: Please note that this Answer is being discussed on meta in [Is an answer that says that other answers are wrong not an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403026/is-an-answer-that-says-that-other-answers-are-wrong-not-an-answer). If you have a solution to the problem, it would be very helpful, if you added it to your Answer here :)

Comment: Undeleting this because (A) it might contain useful information, and (B) it's currently being discussed on Meta, and it's unreasonable to discuss the deletion of an answer when that answer has already been mod-deleted. If you have an opinion about why this answer should or should not be deleted, please post on the Meta question that Scratte linked (do not leave a comment here). Thank you!

Comment: I wonder if your evaluation of @amit's answer is flawed.  Isn't `(w, u, v)` excluded as a path due to caveat he states of treating `u` and `v` like sinks?  So then the path from `w` to `v` would be `(w, x, v)` and the final path would then be `(v, x, w, u)`, which IS a valid path.

Comment: @Steve You are right, I've added another counterexample keeping the caveat in mind

Comment: The "Another counter example" is also incorrect. Not sure why you're talking about the "path" {u,x,w,x,v}. The answer only says that there is a path `v->...->w->...->u`, which is correct (and there's also a path `u->...->v->...->w`). Btw, the examples would be much easier to understand with pictures. Also, making people go through an example only to **afterwards** say that it's incorrect is rather rude. Don't waste people's time.

Comment: @superbrain The question asks for an way to find whether such a path exists, in the "another counter example" BFS may take the u,x,w,x,v path, and report that there is no u-v-w path (There will probably be many such counter-examples). As for the incorrect example, I'm not sure whether I should delete it or let it remain. I have seen people here provide an "Edit" after they make a mistake and since Steve corrected it, it's only fair that I give him the credit for it

Comment: Also, we cannot claim (for the same reasons) that a path from w to u and a path from w to v implies that a path exists from v to w to u, since the paths from w->u and w->v may contain common vertices

Comment: As you showed, it would find paths `w->...->u` and `w->...->v`. It would thus conclude there is also a path `v->...->w->...->u`, and that happens to be *correct*. Thanks for the edit, now people not interested in that incorrect example know they can skip it.

Comment: "It would thus conclude there is also a path v->...->w->...->u" this cannot be concluded

Comment: I "know", but it still happens to be correct. Note I only said that your counterexample is incorrect, not that their answer is correct.

Comment: My counterexample uses the same labels as the question. Simply relabel the nodes u as v, w as u, and v as w in my counter example, then you obtain the "correct" counterexample to the labelling used by accepted answer

Comment: Your counterexample for Matt is also not necessarily correct. It depends on whether duplicate nodes are allowed on the path. [As Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)#Definitions): *"Some authors do not require that all vertices of a path be distinct and instead use the term **simple path** to refer to such a path"*. And I didn't even find that by reading the article, I found it by ctrl-f-ing for "simple" because I already knew about that (I think that's actually how it was taught in a university course I took). So with that definition, Matt's answer is *correct*.

Comment: The way I was taught, paths which allow repetition are called walks (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Walk.html). I agree it depends on convention, but finding a u-v-w walk is hardly an interesting problem.

Comment: For your *"This gives the "path" {u,x,w,x,v} which is invalid"* argument, that labeling is irrelevant. Again: amit's answer only says that there *is* a path. *Not* what such a path looks like. And indeed there *is* one, namely u-x-w-z-y-v.

Comment: I'd just use the graph with E = {{x,u}, {x,v}, {x,w}}, and state that I'm working on the assumption that "path" is meant as not allowing duplicates.

Comment: in a line graph {v, u, w}, there is a path [u,v,u,w] that passes through v.  There was no requirement that paths must be simple.  Also, you should really comment on my answer if you want to say that it's wrong.

Comment: For some reason you assume a path with repeated nodes is "not a path". It is, it is not a *simple* path - but it is a path. The question does not ask for simple paths. Thus, the counter example you provide, does not hold.

Comment: @amit Did you think about it that way back then, though? What was your point in treating `u` and `v` like sinks?

Comment: @superbrain TBH, I do not recall. Making them sinks could likely be just removed, and making it simpler...

Comment: @amit To me, that seemed like an attempt to look for simple paths. If you have the line graph w-u-v and you start at w and stop at u, then you won't find v and wrongly conclude that there's no path from u to v through w. Unless with path you mean simple path.

Comment: @amit 
"For some reason you assume a path with repeated nodes is "not a path" "   

this depends on convention. According to Wikipedia (and many authors) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)#Walk,_trail,_path), a path that allows repetition is called a "walk"

Answer (score 1):

A naive way to do it is just to find all paths you can take from u to w, and then see if v exists in one of those sets.

Or just see if a path exists from u to v and a path exists from v to w

Comment: A good option but those are very expensive algorithms and are not optimized. It will take a lot of space and time in complicated networks.

Answer (score 1):

Do a BFS starting from `u`. Stop it when you find `v`.

Now, do a BFS from `v`. Stop it when you find `w` and return `true`.

If you don't find `v` in the first BFS or `w` in the second BFS, it means there is no path from `u` to `w` passing through `v` and you can stop the prodecure returning `false`.

Complexity: O(|V| + |E|)

Answer (score 1):

Since the graph is undirected, simply **do a BFS starting from `w`**.

This ensures that if you find paths `w->...->u` and `w->...->v`, there is also a path `v->...->w->...->u`, which is also the shortest path with these restrictions

Comment: Rightly said, can we do a bfs from ```v``` &
it visits both ```u``` and ```w```. 
That would work too.

Comment: @superbrain Title explicitly says: `Determine whether there is a path from vertex **u to v passing through w**`

Comment: @amit Ah, right, title disagrees with the body. Sigh. Why do people do that...